# Format string as date

Tags: c#

I have a string 20100524 (2010 05 24) and I would like to parse it as an actual date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20100524", "yyyyMMdd", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: that line works but hey there are better solutions here than mine no need to down vote

Answer (score 16):

This will do it for you in a safe manner:

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("20100524", "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    // use dateTime here
}
else
{
    // the string could not be parsed as a DateTime
}
```

Answer (score 6):

DateTime.Parse and Datetime.ParseExact are your friends.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string dateString = "20100524";
string format = "yyyyMMdd";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Comment: Of course, DateTime.Parse(string stringToParse); will work.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: Looked promising but it faults out saying that it doesnt recognize it as a valid dateTime

Comment: Actually for custom date formats like yours, it is necessary to use ParseExact.

Comment: Just tested that code and, once I'd defined types for dateString and format (I've edited the answer to include), and it worked exactly as required - which is pretty much what one would expect since its right. If you're still getting an error then its likely that either a) you've not got the format string right (its case sensitive) or b) you're not giving it a valid date.