# Win32: How to convert string to a date?

Tags: windows, datetime, parsing, datetime-format, string-parsing

In Windows, i want to parse a `string` as a `date` using an exact format string.

For example, given the string

```
"6/12/2010"
```

and the format:

```
"M/d/yyyy"
```

i want to convert the string to a date, while ensuring that the date matches the format.

i also need to be able to specify the Y2K sliding window, pivot. This means that if a 2-digit year is (correctly) entered, i will specify that number of years in the future i would consider the year to be. e.g.:

```
Two-digit Year    Pivot    Four-digit year
==============    =====    ===============
30                +0       1929
30                +18      1929
30                +19      1929
30                +20      2029
30                +21      2029
30                +100     2029
```

---

.NET already provides a `DateTime.ParseExact` function, which performs nearly exactly what i need:

```
date = DateTime.ParseExact("6/12/2010", 
         DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern,
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Except i can't tell it the 100-year pivot value.

More examples:

```
String        Format Specifier        Date
"6/7/2029"   "M/d/yyyy"             6/7/2029
"6/7/29"     "M/d/yyyy"             (invalid, year too short)
"6/7/29"     "M/d/yy"               6/7/1929  (+0 pivot)
"6/7/29"     "M/d/yy"               6/7/2029  (+100 pivot
"6/7/29"     "M/d/yy"               6/7/2029  (+50 pivot)
"6/7/29"     "M/d/yy"               6/7/2029
"6/7/2029"   "M.d.yyyy"             (invalid, incorrect separators)
"6.7.2029"   "M.d.yyyy"             6/7/2029
"6.7.2029"   "M-d-yyyy"             (invalid, incorrect separators)
"6/7/2029"   "M/dd/yyyy"            (invalid, days requires leading zero)
"6/07/2029"  "M/dd/yyyy"            (invalid, days requires leading zero)    
"6/07/2029"  "MM/dd/yyyy"           (invalid, months requires leading zero)
"06/07/2029  "MM/dd/yyyy"           6/7/2029
"06/07/2029" "MM/d/yyyy"            (invalid, days should not have leading zero)
"06/7/2029"  "MM/d/yyyy"            6/7/2029
```

i know that Windows doesn't have native API to convert a string to a date.

Is there any established code out there that will convert a `string` to a `date` using a format specifier? Computers have been around for a while now; someone must have solved this problem already.

Here is a list of some sample format specifiers that you could be expected to see in Windows:

- `M/d/yyyy`
- `M/d/yy`
- `M/dd/yyyy`
- `M/dd/yy`
- `MM/d/yyyy`
- `MM/d/yy`
- `MM/dd/yyyy`
- `MM/dd/yy`
- `d/M/yyyy`
- `d/M/yyy`
- `d/MM/yyyy`
- `d/MM/yy`
- `dd/M/yyyy`
- `dd/M/yy`
- `dd/MM/yyyy`
- `dd/MM/yy`
- `yyyy/M/d`
- `yy/M/d`
- `yyyy/MM/d`
- `yy/MM/d`
- `yyyy/MM/dd`
- `yy/MM/dd`
- `dd MM yyyy`
- `dd.MM.yyyy`

### See also

- MSDN: [Day, Month, Year, and Era Format Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317787(v=VS.85).aspx)
- MSDN: [LOCALE_SSHORTDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373886(VS.85).aspx)
- Stackoverflow: [Format string as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902563/format-string-as-date)
- Stackoverflow: [Parse a Date from a String in Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234171/parse-a-date-from-a-string-in-win32)
- MSDN: [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx)
- Stackoverflow: [Convert String To date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222851/convert-string-to-date-in-php)

Comment: i can keep fiddling with it until someone gets it, but admits it's too difficult a problem to solve.

Comment: Win32 does have [an API to convert a string to a date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221395.aspx), but it doesn't give enough control over the process.  What you really wanted was `strptime`, which [Windows doesn't implement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows) except as [part of the Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-my/library/cc754234.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i eventually had to cave in and write one. Not trivial to parse a date

```
class function TDateTimeUtils.TryStrToDateExact(const S, DateFormat: string; out Value: TDateTime): Boolean;
begin
{
    Assume Microsoft's de-facto standard for y2k fixup: 2029
        1930-2029
}
    Result := TDateTimeUtils.TryStrToDateExact(S, DateFormat, 2029, {out}Value);
end;

class function TDateTimeUtils.TryStrToDateExact(const S, DateFormat: string; PivotYear: Integer;
        out Value: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
    Month, Day, Year: Integer;
    Tokens: TStringDynArray;
    CurrentToken: string;
    i, n: Integer;
    Partial: string;
    MaxValue: Integer;
    nCurrentYear: Integer;

    function GetCurrentYear: Word;
    var
        y, m, d: Word;
    begin
        DecodeDate(Now, y, m, d);
        Result := y;
    end;
begin
    Result := False;
{
    M/dd/yy

    Valid pictures codes are

        d       Day of the month as digits without leading zeros for single-digit days.
        dd      Day of the month as digits with leading zeros for single-digit days.
        ddd Abbreviated day of the week as specified by a LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME* value, for example, "Mon" in English (United States).
                Windows Vista and later: If a short version of the day of the week is required, your application should use the LOCALE_SSHORTESTDAYNAME* constants.
        dddd    Day of the week as specified by a LOCALE_SDAYNAME* value.

        M       Month as digits without leading zeros for single-digit months.
        MM      Month as digits with leading zeros for single-digit months.
        MMM Abbreviated month as specified by a LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME* value, for example, "Nov" in English (United States).
        MMMM    Month as specified by a LOCALE_SMONTHNAME* value, for example, "November" for English (United States), and "Noviembre" for Spanish (Spain).

        y       Year represented only by the last digit.
        yy      Year represented only by the last two digits. A leading zero is added for single-digit years.
        yyyy    Year represented by a full four or five digits, depending on the calendar used. Thai Buddhist and Korean calendars have five-digit years. The "yyyy" pattern shows five digits for these two calendars, and four digits for all other supported calendars. Calendars that have single-digit or two-digit years, such as for the Japanese Emperor era, are represented differently. A single-digit year is represented with a leading zero, for example, "03". A two-digit year is represented with two digits, for example, "13". No additional leading zeros are displayed.
        yyyyy   Behaves identically to "yyyy".

        g, gg   Period/era string formatted as specified by the CAL_SERASTRING value.
                The "g" and "gg" format pictures in a date string are ignored if there is no associated era or period string.


        PivotYear
                The maximum year that a 1 or 2 digit year is assumed to be.
                The Microsoft de-factor standard for y2k is 2029. Any value greater
                than 29 is assumed to be 1930 or higher.

                e.g. 2029:
                    1930, ..., 2000, 2001,..., 2029

                If the PivotYear is between 0 and 99, then PivotYear is assumed to be
                a date range in the future. e.g. (assuming this is currently 2010):

                    Pivot   Range
                    0       1911..2010  (no future years)
                    1       1912..2011
                    ...
                    98      2009..2108
                    99      2010..2099  (no past years)

                0 ==> no years in the future
                99 ==> no years in the past
}
    if Length(S) = 0 then
        Exit;
    if Length(DateFormat) = 0 then
        Exit;

    Month := -1;
    Day := -1;
    Year := -1;

    Tokens := TDateTimeUtils.TokenizeFormat(DateFormat);
    n := 1; //input string index
    for i := Low(Tokens) to High(Tokens) do
    begin
        CurrentToken := Tokens[i];
        if CurrentToken = 'MMMM' then
        begin
            //Long month names, we don't support yet (you're free to write it)
            Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'MMM' then
        begin
            //Short month names, we don't support yet (you're free to write it)
            Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'MM' then
        begin
            //Month, with leading zero if needed
            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 2{MinDigits}, 2{MaxDigits}, 1{MinValue}, 12{MaxValue}, {var}Month) then Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'M' then
        begin
            //months
            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 1{MinDigits}, 2{MaxDigits}, 1{MinValue}, 12{MaxValue}, {var}Month) then Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'dddd' then
        begin
            Exit; //Long day names, we don't support yet (you're free to write it)
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'ddd' then
        begin
            Exit; //Short day names, we don't support yet (you're free to write it);
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'dd' then
        begin
            //If we know what month it is, and even better if we know what year it is, limit the number of valid days to that
            if (Month >= 1) and (Month <= 12) then
            begin
                if Year > 0 then
                    MaxValue := MonthDays[IsLeapYear(Year), Month]
                else
                    MaxValue := MonthDays[True, Month]; //we don't know the year, assume it's a leap year to be more generous
            end
            else
                MaxValue := 31; //we don't know the month, so assume it's the largest

            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 2{MinDigits}, 2{MaxDigits}, 1{MinValue}, MaxValue{MaxValue}, {var}Day) then Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'd' then
        begin
            //days
            //If we know what month it is, and even better if we know what year it is, limit the number of valid days to that
            if (Month >= 1) and (Month <= 12) then
            begin
                if Year > 0 then
                    MaxValue := MonthDays[IsLeapYear(Year), Month]
                else
                    MaxValue := MonthDays[True, Month]; //we don't know the year, assume it's a leap year to be more generous
            end
            else
                MaxValue := 31; //we don't know the month, so assume it's the largest

            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 1{MinDigits}, 2{MaxDigits}, 1{MinValue}, MaxValue{MaxValue}, {var}Day) then Exit;
        end
        else if (CurrentToken = 'yyyy') or (CurrentToken = 'yyyyy') then
        begin
            //Year represented by a full four or five digits, depending on the calendar used.
            {
                Thai Buddhist and Korean calendars have five-digit years.
                The "yyyy" pattern shows five digits for these two calendars,
                    and four digits for all other supported calendars.
                Calendars that have single-digit or two-digit years, such as for
                    the Japanese Emperor era, are represented differently.
                    A single-digit year is represented with a leading zero, for
                    example, "03". A two-digit year is represented with two digits,
                    for example, "13". No additional leading zeros are displayed.
            }
            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 4{MinDigits}, 4{MaxDigits}, 0{MinValue}, 9999{MaxValue}, {var}Year) then Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'yyy' then
        begin
            //i'm not sure what this would look like, so i'll ignore it
            Exit;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'yy' then
        begin
            //Year represented only by the last two digits. A leading zero is added for single-digit years.
            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 2{MinDigits}, 2{MaxDigits}, 0{MinValue}, 99{MaxValue}, {var}Year) then Exit;

            nCurrentYear := GetCurrentYear;
            Year := (nCurrentYear div 100 * 100)+Year;

            if (PivotYear < 100) and (PivotYear >= 0) then
            begin
                //assume pivotyear is a delta from this year, not an absolute value
                PivotYear := nCurrentYear+PivotYear;
            end;

            //Check the pivot year value
            if Year > PivotYear then
                Year := Year - 100;
        end
        else if CurrentToken = 'y' then
        begin
            //Year represented only by the last digit.
            if not ReadDigitString(S, n, 1{MinDigits}, 1{MaxDigits}, 0{MinValue}, 9{MaxValue}, {var}Year) then Exit;

            nCurrentYear := GetCurrentYear;
            Year := (nCurrentYear div 10 * 10)+Year;

            if (PivotYear < 100) and (PivotYear >= 0) then
            begin
                //assume pivotyear is a delta from this year, not an absolute value
                PivotYear := nCurrentYear+PivotYear;
            end;

            //Check the pivot year value
            if Year > PivotYear then
                Year := Year - 100;
        end
        else
        begin
            //The input string should contains CurrentToken starting at n
            Partial := Copy(S, n, Length(CurrentToken));
            Inc(n, Length(CurrentToken));
            if Partial <> CurrentToken then
                Exit;
        end;
    end;

    //If there's still stuff left over in the string, then it's not valid
    if n <> Length(s)+1 then
    begin
        Result := False;
        Exit;
    end;

    if Day > MonthDays[IsLeapYear(Year), Month] then
    begin
        Result := False;
        Exit;
    end;

    try
        Value := EncodeDate(Year, Month, Day);
    except
        Result := False;
        Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
end;

class function TDateTimeUtils.TokenizeFormat(fmt: string): TStringDynArray;
var
    i: Integer;
    partial: string;

    function IsDateFormatPicture(ch: AnsiChar): Boolean;
    begin
        case ch of
        'M','d','y': Result := True;
        else Result := False;
        end;
    end;
begin
    SetLength(Result, 0);

    if Length(fmt) = 0 then
        Exit;

    //format is only one character long? If so then that's the tokenized entry
    if Length(fmt)=1 then
    begin
        SetLength(Result, 1);
        Result[0] := fmt;
    end;

    partial := fmt[1];
    i := 2;
    while i <= Length(fmt) do
    begin
        //If the characters in partial are a format picture, and the character in fmt is not the same picture code then write partial to result, and reset partial
        if IsDateFormatPicture(partial[1]) then
        begin
            //if the current fmt character is different than the running partial picture
            if (partial[1] <> fmt[i]) then
            begin
                //Move the current partial to the output
                //and start a new partial
                SetLength(Result, Length(Result)+1);
                Result[High(Result)] := partial;
                Partial := fmt[i];
            end
            else
            begin
                //the current fmt character is more of the same format picture in partial
                //Add it to the partial
                Partial := Partial + fmt[i];
            end;
        end
        else
        begin
            //The running partial is not a format picture.
            //If the current fmt character is a picture code, then write out the partial and start a new partial
            if IsDateFormatPicture(fmt[i]) then
            begin
                //Move the current partial to the output
                //and start a new partial
                SetLength(Result, Length(Result)+1);
                Result[High(Result)] := partial;
                Partial := fmt[i];
            end
            else
            begin
                //The current fmt character is another non-picture code. Add it to the running partial
                Partial := Partial + fmt[i];
            end;
        end;

        Inc(i);
        Continue;
    end;

    //If we have a running partial, then add it to the output
    if partial <> '' then
    begin
        SetLength(Result, Length(Result)+1);
        Result[High(Result)] := partial;
    end;
end;

class function TDateTimeUtils.ReadDigitString(const S: string; var Pos: Integer;
            MinDigits, MaxDigits: Integer; MinValue, MaxValue: Integer;
            var Number: Integer): Boolean;
var
    Digits: Integer;
    Value: Integer;
    Partial: string;
    CandidateNumber: Integer;
    CandidateDigits: Integer;
begin
    Result := False;
    CandidateNumber := -1;
    CandidateDigits := 0;

    Digits := MinDigits;
    while Digits <= MaxDigits do
    begin
        Partial := Copy(S, Pos, Digits);
        if Length(Partial) < Digits then
        begin
            //we couldn't get all we wanted. We're done; use whatever we've gotten already
            Break;
        end;

        //Check that it's still a number
        if not TryStrToInt(Partial, Value) then
            Break;

        //Check that it's not too big - meaning that getting anymore wouldn't work
        if (Value > MaxValue) then
            Break;

        if (Value >= MinValue) then
        begin
            //Hmm, looks good. Keep it as our best possibility
            CandidateNumber := Value;
            CandidateDigits := Digits;
        end;

        Inc(Digits); //try to be greedy, grabbing even *MORE* digits
    end;

    if (CandidateNumber >= 0) or (CandidateDigits > 0) then
    begin
        Inc(Pos, CandidateDigits);
        Number := CandidateNumber;
        Result := True;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project settings allow you to include ATL headers you can use the COleDateTime object (#include atlcomtime.h) and use its handy ParseDateTime method. It is not foolproof, but it does handle many formats OK.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax will let you set the .NET pivot year.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx